# Callback functions for notification in Android

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

How can I detect if the user press Clear All button or the notification is cleared by pushing sideway or notification is clicked? I need to clear some data when the notification is processed? I found the related post here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976634/callback-on-clear-all-button-in-notification-area). But it needs an extra class to set up. Is there any simpler way just to clear the data once the notification has been processed.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect a clearing of a `Notification` you must send a `BroadCast` with the `deleteIntent` and to catch this `broadcast` you need to Create a `BroadCastReceive`. So you have to do the basic things which are noted in the link you shared. So I don't see any other simpler way than that. You can do one thing, that instead of creating a different java file for the `BroadCastReceiver` you can declare it within your service, But it is the same thing as before.

Comment: For the user clicks the notification, how should i detect?

Comment: sorry couldnt understand your comment? can you please describe

Comment: I have one intent already for activation of an activity. How to use the same intent to implement the clear notification?

Comment: Sorry my query is to detect the clear action and to detect when the user click the notification. When the user clicks, the notification is also cleared, is it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5817024/931982 check this to detect if your activity started from notification

Comment: Yeah I found another [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465849/how-to-use-notification-deleteintent) for clear action. Thanks